# Tcl wasn't properly installed on Anacondas

Tags: pydev, python-3.3, anaconda

I have a fairly new install of Anaconda with Python 3.3, and am using Pydev.

When I try to use tkinter with

```
from tkinter import Tk

master = Tk() # create a Tk root widget, which is a window
```

I get the following message

```
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    C:/Anaconda/envs/p33/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Anaconda/envs/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Anaconda/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Anaconda/envs/library C:/Anaconda/library C:/Anaconda/tcl8.5.11/library C:/tcl8.5.11/library
```

This page (http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-March/599573.html) suggests that I need to change the TCL_LIBRARY environment variable.  But I do not know how to do that.

How can I make tkinter work with my build?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a proper solution, but I got it to work by copying the folders

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\p33\tcl\tcl8.5
C:\Anaconda\envs\p33\tcl
```

to

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\p33\Lib
```